# How to get a component based on a string value?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a react component based on user input.

Imagine we have 3 react Components. ChildA, ChildB, ChildC.
If a user select option B then i want to render him ChildB component.

```
    import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

    export const Parent = (props) => {

        const [value, setValue] = useState('B')
        const [child, setChild] = useState('')

        useEffect(()=>{
            setChild(`<Child${value} />`)
        },[value])

        return(
            <div>
                {child}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

But instead of rendering ChildB component. React is rendering it as a ChildB string in DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an object to define a key/value pair like this:

```
const components = {
  'B': ChildB,
  'C': ChildC
};
```

Then when you want to render them conditionally you can use:

```
const MyComponent = components['B'];
return <MyComponent />;
```

Edit: Since the above method requires each component to be defined explicitly, you could use the imported alias `components` instead:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import * as components from "../components";

export const Parent = (props) => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('B')
    const [child, setChild] = useState(null);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const ChildComponent = components[`Child${value}`];
        setChild(<ChildComponent />)
    }, [value])

    return(
        <div>
            {child}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you can import your components like this: `import * as components from "../components"` then you should be able to iterate over the components and produce the object literal above without specifying the components directly.

Comment: @FishLegs I have updated my answer. Hopefully it is a solution for you

Answer (score 1):

This will not work the way you are try to achieve. You can try this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

    export const Parent = (props) => {

        const [value, setValue] = useState('B');

        return(
            <div>
                {value === "A" && <ChildA />}
                {value === "B" && <ChildB />}
                {value === "C" && <ChildC />}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: What if you have hundreds of component. React is primitive framework. Vanilla JS could do it in 2 lines.